# Is it possible to define a wildcard attribute in DTD?

Tags: xhtml, dtd

I am wondering if there is any chance to create a wildcard attribute list in xhtml. E.g.

```
   ?><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd" [
      <!ATTLIST a tooltip CDATA #IMPLIED>
      <!ATTLIST a tooltip-align (top|bottom|right|left) #IMPLIED>
    ]>
```

Instead of "a" I would like to add these two attributes to all elements. Any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The [XHTML DTD](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/dtds.html#a_dtd_XHTML-1.0-Strict) works around this with entity declarations, something like this (simplified):

```
<!ENTITY % coreattrs
 "id          ID             #IMPLIED
  class       CDATA          #IMPLIED
  style       %StyleSheet;   #IMPLIED
  title       %Text;         #IMPLIED"
  >

<!ELEMENT a %a.content;>
<!ATTLIST a
  %coreattrs;
  href        %URI;          #IMPLIED
  ... etcetera ...
  >
```